# How to create checkbox on jsp based on availability?

Tags: java, html, jsp, checkbox, ejb

I want to create checkboxes on jsp based on availability such that for instance, items that have stock above 0 will then be displayed on the page for purchase. So, for instance, if there are 3 available items 3 checkboxes will be created for the 3 items and i do not want to display those that are of 0 stock. Is there a way i can do this on jsp?

ps. I have an item entity in my java database which will let me know the number of stocks available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass this item entity to the model (so it'll be accessible from JSP).

Then you can use [forEach](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm) tag from JSTL core to iterate from 1 to number of items available and display checkbox for each item.

Assuming that you have your entity as a model variable with name 'myItem' and your entity has a field `availableCount`, which stores the number of available items, you can do it like this:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="myItem.availableCount">
  <label>
    Item <c:out value="${i}"/>
    <input type='checkbox' value='item<c:out value="${i}"/>' />
  </label>
</c:forEach>
```

Note that in order to use JSTL core tags, you have to use appropriate taglib import declaration in your JSP file. Read more [here ("Core Tags")](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm).